# Are there available python bindinds for e2fsprogs/e2fslibs?

Tags: python, linux, binding, python-bindings

I have just started [trying to automate the steps](https://github.com/rbrito/scripts/blob/master/lba_problem.py) am trying to automate the steps listed in the [Bad Blocks HOWTO](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html) for reallocating damaged sectors of a hard drive (after some unfortunate events).

Unfortunately, the method that I have so far is to use a pipe with programs from the `e2fsprogs` package and parse its output, which I think is not a robust solution to the problem.

To avoid such parsing, I tried to find python bindings for `e2fslibs` (the libraries that `e2fsprogs` use), but I was not successful in my quest.

So, short from me implementing the bindings myself (and contributing them back) or implementing parsing the output of the programs that I need the right way, are there any python bindings already available for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing them using `ctypes`. Depending on what you want to do, it might get a lot of work...